# Intl.NumberFormat space character does not match

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm running into an issue where `Intl.NumberFormat` is formatting the space character in some way that is different from what Jest is expecting.  Tests against the same function with values that do not yield spaces as separators pass fine.  Jest is considering the space between the 4 and the 5 characters to be different.  I am using the `intl` polyfill for fr_CA both in my app and in my test.

Here is my function, but  the only really relevant part is the `Intl.NumberFormat` output.  How can I reconcile the formatting for the space character so that my test passes?

```
  export function formatCurrency( num, locale = 'en_US', showFractionDigits = false) {
    const options = {
        style: locale === 'fr_CA' ? 'decimal' : 'currency',
        currency: locale.length && locale.indexOf('CA') > -1 ? 'CAD' : 'USD'
    };

    const final = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale.replace('_', '-'), options).format(num);

    if (locale === 'fr_CA') {
        return `${final} $`;
    } else {
        return final;
    }
  }
```

My assertion:

```
expect(formatCurrency(24555.55, 'fr_CA', true)).toBe('24 555,55 $');
```

Result:

```
Expected value to be:
  "24 555,55 $"
Received:
  "24 555,55 $"
```

Comment: I don't see difference in your expected and received. Do you have typo there?

Comment: There is no typo. That's the whole point of this question.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
'11 111.11'.split('').map(x => console.log((x.charCodeAt(0))))
```

Yields "32" for the space character which is a normal space.

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-CA').format(11111.11).split('').map(x => console.log((x.charCodeAt(0))))
```

Yields "160" for the space character, which is a *non-breaking* space.

To make these tests pass, you need to add the non-breaking space UTF-16 (\xa0) character code into the assertion.

```
expect(formatCurrency(24555.55, 'fr_CA', true)).toBe('24\xa0555,55 $');
```

Comment: Wow, I spent way too much time banging my head trying to solve this. Glad I landed here later than never.

Comment: What is the reason for this? Is there a way to tell `Intl` to use the normal `\x20` space character?

Comment: @andersnylund  This is the desired/correct behavior.  Dollars and cents should never be on to two different lines.  It's just something you don't think about until you go to test it.

Answer (score 28):

NumberFormat use small non-breaking space (`\u202f`) for thousand separator and normal non-breaking space beforece currency (`\xa0`)

```js
  expect(new Intl.NumberFormat("fr-FR", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "EUR",
  }).format(126126)).toBe("126\u202f126,00\xa0€")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the `\u202f` character !

Comment: `expect(actualResult.replace(/\xa0/g, ' ').replace(/\u202f/g, ' ')).toEqual(expectedResult)`

Answer (score 2):

Because every jest-fails-on-whitespace question points here, I feel it's necessary to say many cases might be served by checking for whitespace rather than specific characters. Using `.toMatch()` with a regex containing the `\W` character will match either space or non-breaking space:

```
expect(formatCurrency(24555.55, 'fr_CA', true)).toMatch(/24\W555,55\W$/);
```

It also matches a small non-breaking space:

```
expect(new Intl.NumberFormat("fr-FR", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "EUR",
}).format(126126)).toMatch(/126\W126,00\W€/)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the character for the thousand separator that Intl.NumberFormat uses (for example in case you using locale: 'fr_US') this is what you are looking for:

`\u202f`

Example:

```
    const numberToFormat = '1000000.012345678912345678';
    const expectedFR = '1\u202f000\u202f000,012345678912345678';
    expect(Intl.NumberFormat('fr-US').format(numberToFormat).toBe(expectedFR);
```